# Application of Reflection Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function whose modulus is constant on some circle.  Show that $f(z)=c(z-z_0)$ for some $n\geq 0$ and some constant $c$, where $z_0$ is the center of the circle.

So far I have the following idea:

Define $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}$ and show that $g$ is constant.  Now it suffices to show that g is entire and bounded, because then Liouville's Theorem will apply.
If $f(z_0)=0$, then $f(z)=h(z)(z-z_0)$ for some $n>0$ where $h(z_0)\neq0$.  Then $M=|f(z)|=|h(z)||z-z_0|^n=|h(z)|r^n$ on the circle.  Then $|h(z)|=\frac{M}{r^n}$ is constant.  So $h$ is constant since $h(z_0)\neq0$.  Hence we have he result for this case.

Now assume that $f(z_0)\neq0$.

And now I think I will have to apply the Reflection Principle, but I am not sure I understand quite how the principle works yet.  Any help would be appreciated.